# iOS 9 CloudKit: query does not return anything while connected to cellular network

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm developing an app with xcode 7 beta 5. When i run my app on my iphone 6 and i try to connect it to CloudKit if my iphone works in wifi mode all it's ok, i display all my data; but if my iphone works in LTE mode i can't see any kind of data. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
    func getRecordsFromCloud() {  

    lavori = []  

    /  

    let _cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()  
    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase  

    /  

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)  
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Lavori", predicate: predicate)  

    /  

    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)  

    queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["image","name"]  
    queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh  
    queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50  

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord) -> Void in  

        let lavoriRecord = record  

        self.lavori.append(lavoriRecord)  



    }  

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor?, error:NSError?) -> Void in  

        if (error != nil) {  

            print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")  

        }  
        else {  

            print("Successfully retrieve the data from iCloud")  

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {  
                self.tableView.reloadData()  

            })  

        }  

    }  

    /  

    publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)  

}
```

Thanks, Alessio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the settings app, find your app, enable 'use mobile data'

**Update:** As discussed below
Adding the following line of code solved the problem:

```
queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive
```

The reason why this works must be a timing / load issue. My initial guess would be that this is caused by this line:

```
queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
```

The documentations states for the `.queuePriority` this:
You should use priority values only as needed to classify the relative priority of non-dependent operations.

The documentation states for the `.qualityOfService` this: 
The default value of this property is NSOperationQualityOfServiceBackground and you should leave that value in place whenever possible.

So please try removing both the `.queuePriority` and `.qualityOfService` and see if it's working.

**Update 2:** Apparently this is a CloudKit bug. More people have the same issue. Please report it at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Strange, can't think of any other reason than that. Of course technically you are on a different network. This is not a code issue, it's a network issue. In that case you should get an error. Was there an error printed??

Comment: I also think it's strange ...In the same app I have an rss reader and it works perfectly with wifi and LTE ... I have not any kind of error printed

Comment: could you try setting queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive

Comment: O and could you try setting a print statement in the recordFetchedBlock to see if any records are coming in. Maybe you have some other code that cleans the self.lavori somewhere. It could then be a timing issue (3G is slow, WiFi is fast)

Comment: thank you, just get to the office I try and let you know!

Comment: I do not know why but then entering queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive everything works perfectly! I thank you so much!

Comment: If i remove both the .queuePriority and .qualityOfService it doesn't works. Else working perfectly!

Comment: It's good that it works, but there must be a problem with your code somewhere. It should work without the .quelityOfService and .queuePriority. And then it's still strange that you do not get an error.

Comment: https://twitter.com/bobard/status/644986352203751424 conversation with a CloudKit team member

Comment: Spent a few days searching for a bug. As it turned out it was the change of the default value (qualityOfService) to NSOperationQualityOfServiceBackground with iOS 9.

Comment: I'm still getting this issue (able to fetch from CloudKit when on wifi but not when on cellular data). Have followed the suggestions above and on this link - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/22052. i.e. set QoS to userInteractive, set 'allowsCellularAccess' to true, checked that app can access cellular data on my iphone. Still unresolved. Does anybody have any updates on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in the end by turning on the iCloud Drive data setting. This is actually quite hard to find. I'm on ios 14.1. My path to the setting was:

Settings -> Mobile Data - (then right at the bottom of Mobile Data) -> iCloud Drive.

I toggled this on and then everything works.

[image: iCloud Drive data setting location]