# iOS 9 GM: CloudKit query does not return anything while connected to cellular network

Tags: ios, ios9, cloudkit, cellular-network

The queries just hang for minutes, no errors, no nothing, `QueryCompletionBlock` just never called. Once I connect to WiFi net, the query immediately return expected result. Meanwhile on iOS 8, same app, same container, same database - all work like a charm.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493698/cloudkit-error-connection-to-my-database-only-in-wifi-mode/32494889#32494889

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to check this one right now...

Comment: @EdwinVermeer You were right. Indeed the same issue.

Comment: This is a CloudKit bug, please report it at https://bugreport.apple.com