# Cloudkit: CKDatabaseOperation not working on cellular

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cellular-network

Hi to all the `CloudKit` users:

I had a horrible time trying to find out why `CKDatabaseOperation` wouldn't give any feedback. No errors, no callbacks when saving `CKRecords` on cellular.

Could you please let me know what is your opinion regarding this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 CloudKit: query does not return anything while connected to cellular network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493698/ios-9-cloudkit-query-does-not-return-anything-while-connected-to-cellular-netwo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone in the Developer Forums of Apple found a solution:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20047

the magic happens when setting `qualityOfService = .UserInitiated`

**Example:**

```
let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase    
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [aRecord], recordIDsToDelete: nil)

operation.allowsCellularAccess = true
operation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated // <----- THATS THE CELLULAR FIX

operation.perRecordProgressBlock = {(record, progress) in
    print("Progress: \(Int(progress*100.0))%")
}
operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {(record, error) in
    print("Upload complete") //Add awesome error handling here
}
publicDB.addOperation(operation)
```

Comment: I love how there is literally zero documentation on this :)