# CKQueryOperation not returning error when device offline

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am trying to use `CKQueryOperation`, rather then `performQuery` on my CloudKit database.

Both work, but when using a CKQueryOperation I am not getting an error when the device is offline, but I do when using `performQuery`

Here is the bare bones my `performQuery` example, database is my `CKDatabase`

```
database.performQuery(q, inZoneWithID: nil) { (records:[CKRecord]?, error:NSError?) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
}
```

An error is given when the device is offline, allowing me to prompt the user. The error is

**`The internet connection appears to be offline`**

However, I get no errors when I use a `CKQueryOperation`

```
let p = NSPredicate(format:"recordID IN %@", student.courses)
let q = CKQuery(recordType: String(Course), predicate: p)

let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: q)

queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
    // not called without network connection - doesn't enter scope
    print(record)
}


queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) in
    // not called without network connection - doesn't enter scope
    print(cursor)
    print(error)
}

database.addOperation(queryOperation)
```

With a connection I receive my data for both methods so it is working as expected.

How / Where am I informed of error when using `CKQueryOperation` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per usual I post a bounty and find the answer within the next hour or 2. Not sure how I missed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189458/cloudkit-ckdatabaseoperation-not-working-on-cellular) originally but it contained the answer I was looking for.

So by adding this line

```
queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
```

something behind the scenes changes and we have some nice action within

```
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) in
    // We get an error message... Finally !!
    print(error)
}
```

Couldn't find anything in the Apple Docs to hint at this either.

Comment: I also found that the operations `timeoutIntervalForResource` default value is 7 days... So it might take a week before giving up in the request, even if it sounds silly. I changed it to 6 seconds and voilá

Comment: It looks like the timeout intervals are [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckoperation), but thankfully qualityOfSetting still works. It is now `.userInitiated` in Swift 3.

Comment: My .queryCompletionBlock wasn't being called at all until I added in the .qualityOfService. Thank you!